# How to change inside of a div with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the inside of a div to change. after five seconds the div content stays the same. and I'm stuck..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $div = $("#tiedotteet");

  var timer = setInterval( function() {
   $div.html("<h1>Test</h1>");
  }, 5000);
</script>

<div id="tiedotteet">
```

Comment: Try to add the div before the script in your html.

Comment: Put the `div` before the `script` or use a document.ready event handler. Also note that the interval is pretty redundant, as after the first iteration you won't see any change. Perhaps a `setTimeout()` would be more apt.

Answer (score 2):

DOM elements should be rendered before script. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/5232486

```html
<div id="tiedotteet"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $div = $("#tiedotteet");

  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $div.html("<h1>Test</h1>");
  }, 5000);
</script>
```